# What Does "Hanging a Magpie on a Hedge" Mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I recently heard Roger Waters say "it's a bit like hanging a magpie on a hedge" on the news, but I cannot seem to find any information as to what it means.
You can check out the interview [here](https://www.foxnews.com/transcript/pink-floyds-roger-waters-julian-assange-being-used-as-a-warning-to-other-journalists).

Comment: From the heading "Julian Assange being used as a warning", I guess it may be a reference to the 'gamekeeper's gibbet'. Old-time gamekeepers used to kill predatory animals, and ones regarded as a nuisance such a moles, and string up the corpses on fences or hedges, either to show how efficient they were or as a 'warning' to deter other such creatures.

Comment: that worthy of being an answer

Comment: @KateBunting That seems to be the answer, thank you.